# SQL: Are we able to combine multiple conditions into one result column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I'm standardizing & migrating some of our old data from an ugly heap of a DB into something more useful.

BTW, the source DB is MSSQL/SQL-Server.
(and it's plagued with column and table sprawl, very little use of FK's, and where there are FK's, they are often broken because some unique ID's ***change*** in certain UI use cases !!! :)

Right now, I'm collecting some customer data. There are two main categories of customer here. They are not mutually exclusive. The terminology used is rather cryptic, so I'll simplify it here to *User*, and *Reseller*.

As it stands right now, there are 4 (yes, ***four***) columns in the source table which can be used to determine whether a customer is a *Reseller* or a *User*: `is_user`, `isuser`, `is_reseller`, and `cust_type`.
The `cust_type` column stores hand-typed values, so we face variations in spelling/abbreviations too :)

I already have some earlier queries which select each of the customer types separately, but now I'd like to consolidate those into one qry where the results have a simple `is_user` bool and a simple `is_reseller` bool.

Here's an example of my qry for *users* (trimmed for brevity, functionality intact):

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, email, phone
FROM customer 
WHERE  name = '{$row['cust']}'
AND (  isuser=1 
    OR is_user=1
    OR cust_type LIKE 'USER%'
    OR cust_type = 'DIRECT USER' 
)
```

**My goal** is to eliminate that condition, and replace it with an additional column in the result set to indicate whether `is_user` is TRUE/FALSE.

How doable is this in SQL (specifically the MS flavor)?

Comment: Since the resultset is filtered to only rows that match one of the conditions, won't the additional column be true for every single row?

Comment: +1 Same thought with @AaronBertrand

Comment: Updated my GOAL to better clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression but you need to make sure your `WHERE` clause is less exclusive (if it's the same set of criteria then every row in the result will be true).

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, email, phone, is_user = CASE
   WHEN ( isuser = 1 
      OR is_user = 1
      OR cust_type LIKE 'USER%'
      OR cust_type = 'DIRECT USER')
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
 is_reseller = CASE 
   WHEN (...any condition that makes a customer a reseller...)
   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM dbo.customer
...WHERE...
```

Comment: PEERFECT!!!! That's exactly the type of thing I was looking for.  Thanks-a-bunch.